# Mat73 is taking forever to open a MATLAB .mat file

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5, h5py

I am using mat73 to open `.mat` files on a remote server of about an average size of 1GB. When I run these files locally, it loads the files in <10seconds, however when I run them through a remote connection the files never load >2 minutes. Any idea why this occurs? Is it a remote connection problem?

I reset the conda env, removed mat73 and dependecies. Also tried to open with just h5py, and it didn't work.

What I've tried:
to test if it's a network connection speed problem: I ran speeftestCLI on the cluster got back 750mbit/sec, 850mbit/sec (down/up). downloaded 10 gigs of data in 15ish minutes.
When running MAT73 and H5py locally, a 2gb file will take 7s/0.5s respectively. While running it on my remote connection to VScode the notebook took 70+ minutes (I had to stop it, seemed like it wouldn't work).
I believe it might be a jupyter/python/environment problem. I reinstalled everything. Tried python 3.9 and 3.10. Nothing seems to fix my problem.

I've narrowed down my problem to either mat73 or its h5py dependency. When running `h5py.File('my file.mat')` or `mat73.loadmat('my file.mat')` I get an infinite cycle where nothing happens. I've tried both of these functions on a very small .mat file (though not saved as mat7.3) and it also took a very long time. I believe it might be an issue with the package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your network connection speed? Loading 1GB can take a while if you have a slow internet connection.

Comment: Adding to @Saaru Lindestøkke's comment...Given your code runs must faster locally, it's reasonable to conclude the bottleneck is your network. How long did it take to copy the mat73 file from the server to your local computer? That gives an insight into network performance. That said, `h5py.File()` to open is not memory intensive, so should not take a long time (if that's all you are doing).

Comment: this is good feedback. According to speedtestCLI -> download is 750mbit/s upload 850 mbit/s. However, when downloading the files to the local it takes about 5mins for 1gb. However, I am not downloading the files, I am using VSCode's SSH Remote Connection feature to connect to the server and I'm running my jupyter notebook from there. I thought this would circumvent any network delays.

Comment: Like i mentioned: when I download the data to my local machine and run my script, loading the .mat files take <10 seconds. However, to go around downloading a ton of data I remote connected via VS Code to my job's cluster. I created a .ipynb file, got the same python version and packages and ran my code in this remote connection, but it seems that loading these files isn't working going over 10 minutes before I shut it off.

Comment: @kcw78 Looking further into it, heres more context: for 3 files (10GBs) it downloaded in 20ish minutes, ran through my script in 30 seconds. On the remote connection - I've been running a mat73.loadmat on a single 1.5GB file and it's been over 30 minutes.

Comment: Gee, that's quite some details you omitted in your question. Perhaps you can [edit] it and include things you've tried so far, details about your setup and some structure such that people are not left guessing what your context is.

Comment: Since the problem occurs with remote execution, you need to investigate HW/SW differences compared to your local system. I am not familiar with jupyter notebook running remotely. Does everything execute on the server side? Or is there client-server communication? How much RAM is available for your remote process? How much on your local system?

Answer (score 1):

When diagnosing problems like this, it's easier (and usually faster) to start with something that works, and expand from there. Here is a very simple script to create a small HDF5 file with h5py, close it and reopen. Run it remotely. It should run in an instant.

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('SO_75389309.h5','w') as h5w:
    l1 = [i for i in range(100)]
    h5w.create_dataset('test1',data=l1)   
with h5py.File('SO_75389309.h5') as h5r:
    print(h5r['test1'].shape, h5r['test1'].dtype)
```

Output should be:

```
(100,) int32
```

If it works, keep testing with larger file sizes. Increase the `range()` to create a larger list (or use a `np.array`) and create more datasets (eg, 'test2', 'test3', etc). The goal is to create a large HDF5 file that replicates the performance bottleneck.

If that small example does not run quickly, there's something in your remote configuration (either the notebook, package versions, or the virtual instance on the server). That will be harder to diagnose. You said you tried Python 3.9 and 3.10. What package versions are you using? You can get them with:

```
import h5py
print(h5py.__version__)
```

Comment: so running this first line of code resulted in an infinite loop. I have h5py version 3.8.0

Comment: Which line are you referring to as 1st line: `import h5py` or the h5py.File()` Either way, that's a problem. Instantiating a h5py file object is not compute, memory or I/O intensive.  Clearly there's a problem with your jupyter notebook setup on the cluster. I am out of ideas.

Comment: I think the problem lies in using h5py on remote servers. I started reading and it seems incompatible. Thank you for your help though!